# SyntaxError: invalid label and request status 0 when call webservice

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I want to Access php web service using ajax jquery
This is my code:-

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
    url:'http://localhost:8080/onestatus/webservice/login?email=kk@kk.com&password=123456',
         cache: false,
          dataType: "json",
          success: onSuccess
        });

function onSuccess(data) {
       // var data = data.d;
        var result = $.parseJSON(data);
        var arrayObject = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < result.user.length; i++) {
           // $('#resultLog').append('<li>' + result.user[i].user_id + '</li>');
         }
    }
```

when i use dataType: "json" then i am getting  request.status=0 noting getting in responce

and when use  dataType: "jsonp"  getting error in firbug

**SyntaxError: invalid label
[Break On This Error]

{"user":[{"response":"success","user_id":"28","session_id":123456}]}**

Comment: We need to see onSuccess

Comment: The response is JSON, not JSONP

Comment: Just a reminder, use "for (var i = 0; i < result.user.length; i++) {". Use keyword "var" for local variables. You don't want random globals messing stuff up.

Comment: have any idea what is error or any thing wrong in my code

Comment: try with `dataType: "text"` or `processData : false` attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two cases:

1. The URL `http://localhost:8080/onestatus/webservice/login` is placed on a domain different from the requesting domain(note: the port must match too) : you will not be able to request a JSON, it's restricted by [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)
2. you may request a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) from a different domain, but the received response is not JSONP

So what you can do:
When the webservice is under your control, change the response to proper JSONP. Otherwise you can't do anything.